# What is “duly identified” in the case of preparation research proposal?

Tags: citations, research-proposal, reference-managers

I am going to prepare a research proposal, and I have observed the following statement which I do not understand. Can you help me understand what it means?

> All text, paragraphs or textual phrases from a bibliographic reference, whether by other authors or their own, must be duly identified in the text and in the list of references.

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you quote material from elsewhere (including reusing material from something you previously published), you need to indicated that it’s a quote and cite it correctly.  It’s just a standard statement that your proposal has to comply with normal referencing standards.

Comment: From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duly), duly: "in a due manner or time : PROPERLY"